# Serialization of nested json no definition of fields

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serializa a json. I have created a helper class for it yet it claims that SerializeJsonBody has no definition of the fields I need to fill. When I use the deeper classes the definition is ok yet I won't create the full json.
My end result should look like this:

```
{"invoiceHash": { "hashSHA":{ "algorithm": "SHA-256","encoding": "Base64","value": {0}},"fileSize": {1}}, "invoicePayload":{ "type": "plain","invoiceBody": {2}} }
```

```
public class SerializeJsonBody
{
    public invoiceHash invoiceHash { get; set; }
    public invoicePayload invoicePayload { get; set; }
}
public class invoiceHash
{
    public hashSHA hashSHA { get; set; }
    public string fileSize { get; set; }
}
public class hashSHA
{
    public string algorithm { get; set; }
    public string encoding { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class invoicePayload
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string invoiceBody { get; set; }
}
```

```
SerializeJsonBody body = new SerializeJsonBody
{
    algorithm = "SHA-256",
    encoding = "Base64",
    value = "",
    fileSize = "",
    type = "plain",
    invoiceBody = ""
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, Formatting.Indented);
```

Edit. I think I figured it out.. Not sure if the best way yest it works

```
            SerializeJsonBody body = new SerializeJsonBody
            {
                invoiceHash = new invoiceHash
                {
                    hashSHA = new hashSHA
                    {
                        algorithm = "SHA-256",
                        encoding = "Base64",
                        value = base64hash
                    },
                    fileSize = lenght
                },
                invoicePayload = new invoicePayload
                {
                    type = "plain",
                    invoiceBody = base64
                }

            };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, Formatting.Indented);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method with this signature in the documentation, I strongly recommend that you visit [it](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)
Your issue can be solved with [JsonSerializerSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm)